# Помощь с версткой блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сверстать эти блоки на чистом html и css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда первым делом учишь фреймворки (((

Comment: Используйте display: flex;
https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/

Comment: Изучите технологию `display: flex;`, посмотрите как верстают на ютубе с нуля. Зайдите, прочитайте про флексы, чтобы понимать, что можно делать, как этим управлять https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/

Comment: Берёшь и верстаешь. А если не умеешь от слова совсем, идёшь на биржу фриланса и размещаешь там заказ за денюжку.

Comment: @humster_spb он учится наверно

Comment: @MaximLensky и чему он научится, глядя в готовый код ответа?

Comment: @MaximLensky  Здравствуйте жду инспекцию кода пожалуйста :)

Comment: @leks я же плюс поставил значится все нормально

Comment: @MaximLensky  понял спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1. Развернуть на всю страницу
2. Инспекция кода приветствуется ...

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}  

.block{
  background-color: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}

.span{
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.text{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.text:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -10px;
}

.block2{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;

}

.block2-gl{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block2-circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.block2-text{
  width: 300px;
}

.block2-span{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.block2-span2{
  color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
      <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <span class='span'>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block2-gl">
       <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-circle"></div>
        <div class="sd">
           <p class="block2-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, facere libero vitae, dolorum magnam itaque accusantium. Perspiciatis officiis quasi optio.
           </p>
           <span class="block2-span">Lorem ipsum.</span>
           <span class="block2-span2">Lorem ipsum.</span>
        </div>
  </div>
   <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-circle"></div>
        <div class="sd">
           <p class="block2-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, facere libero vitae, dolorum magnam itaque accusantium. Perspiciatis officiis quasi optio.
           </p>
           <span class="block2-span">Lorem ipsum.</span>
           <span class="block2-span2">Lorem ipsum.</span>
        </div>
  </div>
   <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-circle"></div>
        <div class="sd">
           <p class="block2-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, facere libero vitae, dolorum magnam itaque accusantium. Perspiciatis officiis quasi optio.
           </p>
           <span class="block2-span">Lorem ipsum.</span>
           <span class="block2-span2">Lorem ipsum.</span>
        </div>
  </div>
   <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-circle"></div>
        <div class="sd">
           <p class="block2-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, facere libero vitae, dolorum magnam itaque accusantium. Perspiciatis officiis quasi optio.
           </p>
           <span class="block2-span">Lorem ipsum.</span>
           <span class="block2-span2">Lorem ipsum.</span>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```